# Keeping track of edited location in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, editing, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase

With large datasets, how do you keep track of where you have edited across the map? For instance, I am editing a city's waterline and water valve data. I estimate using a 1:400 average zoom level. This is a large city, and I can quickly lose track of where I have edited, especially after days of working on it.

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 Basic with a file geodatabase. Is there a function to track the location and extent of where my window has been? Or is there a better way to track changes/edited location?

If not, I might write script to make an initial polygon, or draw a feature, based on the current window extents, and then merge new extents to it as I pan across the map. Perhaps stop it from drawing if zoom is beyond 1:1000.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

What I've always done is to add a field to the dataset named "Edited", with a Yes/No domain.  Update all of the unedited data to "No", then change to "Yes" as I edit.  Set the symbology for No to red and Yes to green, and you have a quick visual representation of where you have been, and you can also get a quick count of unedited features as well.

Comment: I do this type of thing, but the problem is that sometimes I need to review an area but no changes are needed. Then, I still need to know I've reviewed it, or other people need to know I've reviewed it... I guess I could touch all the lines/features even tho no edits are being made.

Comment: In that case, instead of calling the column 'Edited' I have had a 'Reviewed' column. You can set a domain for 'No', 'Yes - No changes needed', 'Yes - with changes', if you need to track how many changes actually occurred. Also, Edit tracking is quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

I find the [Editor Tracking tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m600000068000000) to be useful in monitoring what has been done to data. You can easily [enable editor tracking](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000016p000000) to view and review your edits.

Comment: That definately informs upon Zach's answer. I will start implementing this into my workflows. However, my comment to his answer still stands. Sometimes no edits are required, but I still need to have a record of actually having reviewed the area.